# <select> value turns null after updating it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu

So i have this strange problem:

i have a select element with class `"Menu_DDL"`.

i turn it into a jQuery UI `.selectmenu()` the following way:

```
$(".Menu_DDL").selectmenu({
    width: "100%",
    change: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

now i need to update the value programatically, but the select's value does not change:

```
var temp_email = $(this).attr("MID");
    console.log(temp_email);
    console.log("was: " + edit_email_template_dialog.find(".Menu_DDL").val());
edit_email_template_dialog.find(".Menu_DDL").val(temp_email);
    console.log("now: " + edit_email_template_dialog.find(".Menu_DDL").val());
edit_email_template_dialog.find(".Menu_DDL").selectmenu("refresh", true);
    console.log("refreshed");
edit_email_template_dialog.attr("TID", $(this).parents(".TR_Record").attr("TID"));
edit_email_template_dialog.dialog("open");
```

the logs from above return the following:

```
"49" 
"was: 23" 
"now: null" 
"refreshed"
```

as you can see, the value turns into `null` after i try to update it. the weird part is, that if run the same code via console eg `edit_email_template_dialog.find(".Menu_DDL").val("49");` it works fine.

what am i missing?

Comment: Log `edit_email_template_dialog.find(".Menu_DDL").length` as well. Can you share a demo deproducing this..?

Comment: length logs "1". the whole thing is being rendered by asp.net, i will create a post-rendered fiddle in a sec

Comment: i cant wrap my mind around this, it works perfectly in a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/6fjy88w2/) but not on my website...

Comment: Sometimes I have to set the value of a select menu, and all I know is that the appropriate option *might* have the value I'm looking for in the value attribute, or in `.text()`. So I loop through each each option, for example `$(".menu option").each(function(){});`. In the loop I check the value attribute AND `.text()` - if one of them matches then I do `$(".menu").val( $(this).val() );`. I'm not sure if that will be at all helpful in your case, but maybe it's worth a shot. When I do the check, I also make everything lowercase, remove spaces, etc.

Comment: @MikeWillis it would be a good alternative, however for some reason it seems my jquery partially doesnt work on my website... `$(this)` returns the option in jQuery object, but `$(this).val()` returns undefined. **if i run the exact same code from the browser's console, it works**...

Comment: @MikeWillis i've located the issue. i was setting the wrong `"MID"` attribute via asp.net when creating the elements. your comment made me realize that that the values were actually the wrong ones. if you post this as an answer, i will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I have to set the value of a select menu, and all I know is that the appropriate option might have the value I'm looking for in the value attribute, or in `.text()`. So I loop through each each option, checking the value attribute AND `.text()` for example:

```
// assuming var myValue is the value we're looking for
$(".menu option").each(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == myValue || $(this).text() == myValue ) {
        $(".menu").val( $(this).val() );
    }
});
```

You can also make everything lowercase, remove spaces, etc, and print debugging notes:

```
// assuming var myValue is the value we're looking for
myValue = myValue.toLowerCase().replace( / /g, "" );
var currentValue;
var currentText;
$(".menu option").each(function(){
    currentValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase().replace( / /g, "" );
    currentText = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace( / /g, "" );
    console.log("checking if '" + currentValue + "' == '" + myValue + "' OR if '" + currentText + "' == '" + myValue + "'");
    if ( currentValue == myValue || currentText == myValue ) {
        console.log(" ... match found, setting value");
        $(".menu").val( $(this).val() );
    }
});
```

The debugging notes have helped me too. Every once in a while I find a situation where I thought it wasn't finding a match, but it turns out it was (the " ... match found" notice was printed). That helped me figure out that some code later in the same script was resetting the value of the menu.